# Completely stuck. (MongoDB / MERN issue)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

Im creating an app, and right now I'm working on a feature that takes in user input, and stores it in the database. I've done this plenty of times on other projects, but have come to a problem that I just can't solve.

So far, when a user types in their info and hit's enter, the data is sent to the back end, and start's to head towards the endpoint. I have a controller set up with my 'create' function. It is the following:

```
   const db = require('../database/models');

module.exports = {

// create: function(req, res) {
//     console.log('hit controller');
//     db.Listing
//       .create(req.body)
    //       .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    //       .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    //   }

    create: function(req, res) {
    console.log('!!!!HERE:CONTROLLERS' + req.body.receiver);
    db.Listing
        .create(req.body)
        .then(function(dbModel) {
            console.log(dbMessage);
            res.json(dbModel)
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.json(err);
        });
    }
    };
```

I have two functions because I tried something a little different for each with the same result. Once it gets to this point, I get the following error ('hit controller' is just the console.log in the create function):

```
    'hit controller'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

I also get the following error in my console on the browser: xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/listing/ 500 (Internal Server Error) err from saveListing Error: Request failed with status code 500 at createError (createError.js:16) at settle (settle.js:18) at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)

Which is coming from my addListing page:

```
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 console.log('hit');
 console.log("state in handle submit", this.state.title)
    if (
        this.state.title &&
        this.state.description &&
        this.state.duration &&
        this.state.datesAvailable &&
        this.state.tags 
    ) {
        API.saveListing({ 
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            duration: this.state.duration,
            datesAvailable: this.state.datesAvailable,
            tags: this.state.tags
        }) 
            .then(res => console.log('success'))
            .catch((err) => console.log("err from saveListing", err));
    }
};
```

Here is my models file:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var ListingSchema = new Schema({
  // `title` is of type String
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  duration: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  datesAvailable: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  hashtags: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
});


var Listing = mongoose.model("Listing", ListingSchema);


module.exports = Listing;
```

So re-cap: When the user hit's the submit button, the form runs a function, hit's the API with the route it needs, heads to the sever, then to the route for the post request, then the llistingController for the create function for the post, while pulling from my Listing DB model. Once the create function is reached, it poops out. The data is apparently undefined, but I don't know why and can't figure it out.

I feel like what I'm running into is probably basic as fuck but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  Additionally if anyone knows some bad ass resources for adding to my mongo/express/react knowledge i'd love to see it.

Comment: Can I see your models file since I think you have a problem with db.Listing? I think you may forget to export Listing.

Comment: I added the models file to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing `db` from the models file, but that file is exporting `Listing`. Import `Listing` and use  `Listing.create` instead of `db.Listing.create`.

Comment: lmao Thank you! It was so simple! I changed it to 'Listing.create' like you said, and imported the exact file ('../database/models/Listing') instead of the folder and that was it! I thought I could just require the folder and doing db.Listing would find what I needed, but I guess not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As 223seneca said, I changed db.Listing.create in my controller to just Listing.create. Then I required Listing in the controller file to the exact file, instead of to just the models folder('const Listing = require('../database/models/Listing');' instead of 'const Listing = require('../database/models');'.

That was all I needed!